# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type because does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#

```
string_builder.Replace("5 star", "FiveStar");
hotel_pricesURL = string_builder.ToString();
RootobjectOne robjectOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootobjectOne>(hotel_pricesURL);
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<OneStar> one_star_list  = new List<OneStar>();
var  dmx = robjectOne.onestar;
var val = robjectOne.onestar;
var routes_list = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(hotel_pricesURL);

foreach (var forOne in val)
{

}
```

Comment: Pretend, just for a moment, that we don't have access to your code, and thus have *no* idea what e.g. `RootobjectOne` actually is. Do you think we can do more than point out that the error message is telling you - whatever `val` is, it's not something that's enumerable. If you do need more help, please try to construct a [mcve]

Comment: This question is already half-year old. Did you find the answers satisfying? If yes, please consider marking one of them as an actual answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

I think the error message is pretty self explanatory. The problem is your `OneStar` doesn't own `GetEnumerator` method. Which leads to an error, because [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) doesn't know how to iterate over it.

What is interesting, it does not have to be an [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) object, it just has to expose a method:

```
IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
```

As foreach is using enumerator to enumerate through the collection elements. So if you implement in your `OneStar` class a method like this, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to do a forloop on `val`. `Val` is `robjectOne.onestar`. So if `onestar` does not implement `IEnumerable`, your out of luck.

Also whats the use of?

```
var dmx = robjectOne.onestar;
var val = robjectOne.onestar;
```

Comment: Hi RvdK ! I Apologize For Late Response Actually , i have Mistaken by creating two Variable instead One, so I will be using   only  var val = robjectOne.onestar;  and actually the purpose of using this Variable  is to implement a "foreach" loop